# Bootstrap Modal pop-up in Ajax success flush (like shadow) than disappear MVC

Tags: jquery, ajax, popup, bootstrap-modal, asp.net-ajax

i am trying to just show insert record successfully modal pop up inside ajax success it try to come on screen like shadow effect and nothing comes just disappear.

my modal is,

```
<!--Modal PopUp-->
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header alert alert-success">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">@Resource.InfromationDialog</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p class="success-message">@Resource.PrompSuccess </p>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button class="btn btn-success delete-confirm">@Resource.Ok</button>
                    @*<button class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">@Resource.Cancel</button>*@
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

here is my ajax,

```
   $("#create").click(function(e){  
    var myModel =
                {
                    "TribeName": $('#TribeName').val()
                };

var jsonToPost = JSON.stringify(myModel);
$.ajax({
    url: '/Home/Create/',
    async: true,
    processData: false,
    data: jsonToPost,
    type: 'post',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    success: function (data) {
        if (data == true) {
            $('#myModal').modal('show');
        }

    },
    error: function (err) {
        alert('error');

    }
});
})
```

Why it just flashing shadow than disappear it is not showing pop up

EDITED:

here is `#create`,

```
<input type="submit" id="create"  value="@Resource.Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
```

Comment: where is `#create`?

Comment: @Scaramouche i edited my post #create is button id

Comment: i just tried the code and the modal works fine. i cannot try your ajax call obviously because i don't have access to your server, but here's what you can do: make sure to use https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js for the JS and https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css for the CSS, place `console.log(data)` inside success callback to make sure data is true.

Comment: @Scaramouche if i use modal without ajax it works inside ajax it is flushing and it is coming inside success i check by alerting data. i really dont have idea why it is behaving like this :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, since I don't have access to your server, I'll mock the ajax call for this example.

HIH

```js
$("#create").click(function(e){ 

var myModel = {
  "TribeName": $('#TribeName').val()
};

var jsonToPost = JSON.stringify(myModel);
console.log('Sending post request...')
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts',
    async: true,
    processData: false,
    data: jsonToPost,
    type: 'post',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data)
    //in this case data is {"id": 101}, so I have to modify the IF a bit
        //if (data == true) {
        if (data.id == 101) {
            $('#myModal').modal('show');
        }
    },
    error: function (err) {
        console.log('error', err.status);
    }
});
});
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<input type="submit" id="create"  value="@Resource.Create" class="btn btn-primary" />


<!--Modal PopUp-->
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header alert alert-success">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">@Resource.InfromationDialog</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p class="success-message">@Resource.PrompSuccess </p>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button class="btn btn-success delete-confirm">@Resource.Ok</button>
                    @*<button class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">@Resource.Cancel</button>*@
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```